# Creating slideshow in Xpages

Tags: database, image, slideshow, xpages

I am about to create a image slideshow in XPages, all images will refer at the lotus notes database. I don't know how am I going to start on this.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about what you've tried?

Comment: I'd start with the documentation at http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd85forum.nsf/7756aedc25e6d81285256324005ac76c/0a337e87706abb0b852576d4000870c6?OpenDocument or better, what exactly do you mean by start?

Comment: the system will be like this, the user will upload a photo on lotus notes client, all stored images can be view on an xpage slideshow with a fadein and fadeout effect.

Comment: Did you already take a look at openntf.org?

Comment: Have a look at Bildr (available on OpenNTF): it has a built-in slideshow (and uses XPages).

Comment: is it able to use images from the lotus notes database?

Comment: Hi guys! I have now a fade effect on my xpages, and it works (I used dummy image files to test), my problem now how my jquery plugin will read all my images stored on my Lotus Notes database. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you require an **image carousel**. If that is what you are looking for then here are some options -

1. On OpenNTF there is a project called [Home Page Template](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=Home%20Page%20Template) which has an image carousel
2. Another OpenNTF project called [XPages for Presentation](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=XPages%20for%20Presentation). This is not a carousel per se but may give you some ideas.
3. [dojox.image.SlideShow](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojox/image/SlideShow.html) - This [demo page](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/image/tests/test_SlideShow.html) shows it in action

You can also Google "image carousel" to get a lot of third party JavaScript libraries and use them.

Comment: hi there, the nsf files was unable to open at the designer. can you please give me a complete tutorial for creating a carousel inside xpages. the images should be from the lotus notes database

Comment: I am afraid I haven't used these projects. If you are having issue with their NSFs then you can raise defects / discussions on their respective project pages.

Comment: It is inappropriate to ask someone for a complete tutorial.  They would, in essence be doing your work for you.  Take their links and figure it out.  If you have additional specific questions come back and ask them.  You could also contact someone directly and offer to pay them do to the work for you I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these - many jQuery plugins offering differing options for slideshows

http://speckyboy.com/2010/11/14/20-jquery-image-and-multimedia-gallery-plugins

you can add the jQuery plugin to your database (http://notesin9.com/index.php/2012/09/13/notesin9-074-getting-started-with-jquery-plugins-in-xpages/) and go from there

Comment: Hi guys! I have now a fade effect on my xpages, and it works (I used dummy image files to test), my problem now how my jquery plugin will read all my images stored on my Lotus Notes database. thank you.

Comment: Wherever you store the images - they normally have to be displayed on the page and then selected with the plugin. The plugin documentation will tell you what it is expecting to find on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is just too open ended to be answered here I think.  It's certainly doable but sounds like a pretty big and specific undertaking for community support. 
There are some examples on OpenNTF.  that home page app and I think Buildr MIGHT have something in it.  Not sure.  If the NSF files don't open then either contact the project managers or maybe try upgrading your notes client - assuming it's not just an encrypted database.

IdeaJam.net used to have an image carousel on their home page.  Not sure if they still do but if so then maybe looking at the source of that page will help you.
Regarding pulling the images from notes databases I've done something similar to that recently and found Stephan Wissels blog post: http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-86QKNM  extremely helpful.  There is also an OpenNTF project called "myPic" by Jeremy Hodge that does a lot with images as well.

Suggest you research though many of the links, start small...  and you'll eventually get your solution.