# How to create an image slideshow in an xe:Dialog?

Tags: slideshow, xpages, repeat, preload

I am trying to create a slideshow in an xe:dialog

within the dialog I have repeat populated from a notesdocumentcollection containing one image for each document. and two buttons. Next and Previous

When the user in the dialog click "Next" the next image in my collection should be displayed and when I click previous the previous image in my collection should be displayed.

As these images can be very big I do not want to preload them, the actual image should be retrieved at the time when the user click the "Next" button.

How can I do this?

the problem I have is that I do not know how to navigate to the next image. there is probably a very simple solution. I have tried using different techniques like setRowIndex and setIndex etc.

I first thought I could set the repeats repeat limit to "1" and then navigate to next by incrementing the index but could not get that to work.

So what I thought about then was to set the repeat limit to 1000 and hide all images using css but then all images would be preloaded.

Comment: Thomas, what have you tried? and what is your exact problem? Can these suggestions get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13925830/creating-slideshow-in-xpages ?

Comment: Have you looked at using PrettyPhoto for the interface? See Marky Roden's at http://xomino.com/2012/04/03/jquery-in-xpages-4-prettyphoto/

Comment: @Daivd if looks like it is based on the dojo lightbox. I am already using lightbox but it is so enoying that the dialog resized based on the image size so I am doing a nicer solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of document collection, you can store document id's in a vector and put it into viewscope. You also put a current index in the viewScope. Next/previous will change index variable and since xe:dialog supports partial refresh, it will be easy and convenient.

Comment: Yes ofcurse! I was kind of stuck with the repeat solution. thanks!